# how to get name before domain name in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to get sub domain name in my controller like, I have domain name **test.example.com**. I want to get test in my action method and allow site to accept text before domain name.

Comment: you're going to have to be more clear. do you want to pass the URL into the action method?

Comment: only want to get sub domain in action method

Comment: out of curiosity, why is that? might change what the solution is.

Comment: http://www.saved.io/ use this

Comment: ^^ what does that have to do with an actionmethod getting a portion of the  URL of a site?

Comment: i want to store sub domain as category in database as save.io is work ...

Comment: so you want to enter a URL into a textbox and parse it based on the characters in it?

Comment: only sub domain as a parameter in action method